# Is it still possible to post Follow/Unfollow from Instagrams's API?

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I've searched through all of the documentation from Instagram's APIs and I can't find a single mention about posting unfollow / follow. If you could point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This endpoint was available I believe through the legacy Instagram API. However, that was decommissioned a year and a half ago. The replacement Instagram Graph API did bring over these endpoints but they have been decommissioned as well. So I'm afraid it's not possible to follow or unfollow an account using the Instagram API.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/

Instagram API Platform: Deprecation

We will be deprecating the older Instagram API Platform in three phases with complete deprecation occurring in early 2020.

The following will be available until July 31, 2018:

- Follower List - to read the list of followers and followed-by users
- Relationships - to follow and unfollow accounts on a user’s behalf
- Commenting on Public Content - to post and delete comments on a user’s behalf on public media

Comment: Thank you Michael